# Calculate average of every 7 instances in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average, series

I have this pandas dataframe with daily asset prices: 
[Picture of head of Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxe57.png)

I would like to create a pandas series (It could also be an additional column in the dataframe or some other datastructure) with the weakly average asset prices. This means I need to calculate the average on every 7 consecutive instances in the column and save it into a series.

[Picture of how result should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KphY.png)

As I am a complete newbie to python (and programming in general, for that matter), I really have no idea how to start.

I am very grateful for every tipp!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thank you for the infos! It's my first question, so sorry for the mess. I can do better in the future!

Comment: Glad can help! Nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe need [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) by modulo of numpy array create by [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) for general solution also working with all indexes (e.g. with `DatetimeIndex`):

```
np.random.seed(2018)

rng = pd.date_range('2018-04-19', periods=20)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng[::-1], 
                   'ClosingPrice': np.random.randint(4, size=20)})  
#print (df)

df['weekly'] = df['ClosingPrice'].groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 7).transform('mean')
print (df)
    ClosingPrice       Date    weekly
0              2 2018-05-08  1.142857
1              2 2018-05-07  1.142857
2              2 2018-05-06  1.142857
3              1 2018-05-05  1.142857
4              1 2018-05-04  1.142857
5              0 2018-05-03  1.142857
6              0 2018-05-02  1.142857
7              2 2018-05-01  2.285714
8              1 2018-04-30  2.285714
9              1 2018-04-29  2.285714
10             3 2018-04-28  2.285714
11             3 2018-04-27  2.285714
12             3 2018-04-26  2.285714
13             3 2018-04-25  2.285714
14             1 2018-04-24  1.666667
15             0 2018-04-23  1.666667
16             3 2018-04-22  1.666667
17             2 2018-04-21  1.666667
18             2 2018-04-20  1.666667
19             2 2018-04-19  1.666667
```

**Detail**:

```
print (np.arange(len(df)) // 7)
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2]
```

Comment: An additional question came up, maybe you can help again: How can I keep the rows representing the first day of the week (in your example: 2018-04-19, 2018-04-26, 2018-05-03,...) and delete all other rows. In the end I only have one row (with the first day of the week) per weekly price.